# Deployment of a Symfony 6 app with o2switch

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, cpanel

I have trouble deploying my symfony project online. This is a symfony 6 project with a few entities.
My problem is the following: when I go to the domain adress, I can see the index with all my files, even though I defined a route for "/" in my route.yalm file. If I go in my public directory, My Homepage appears with css, js and all but none of the links work.
Here is what I have done.
-I uploaded my file in the corresponding domain on o2switch with the FTP client Filezilla
-I created a database and an SQL user and changed the database URL in my .env file
-I set APP_ENV to prod and APP_DEBUG to 0 in my .env file
-I ran "composer require symfony/requirements-checker"
-I ran composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
-I cleared cache in my o2switch terminal with "APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 php bin/console cache:clear"
Do you know what the problem is and how to fix it?